# cannot import name 'MDBoxLayout' from 'kivy.uix.boxlayout'

Tags: kivy

I tried to run the code from VSCode to OpenCV as follows, but I keep getting this error. How do I solve it?

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
import cv2
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version ! 

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.image = Image()
        layout.add_widget(self.image)
        self.save_img_button = MDRaisedButton(
            text="CLICK HERE",
            pos_hint = {'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.5},
            size_hint = (None, None))
        self.save_img_button.bind(on_press=self.take_picture)
        layout.add_widget(self.save_img_button)
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.load_video, 1.0/30.0)
        return layout
    
    def load_video(self, *args):
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        # Frame initialize
        self.image_frame = frame
        buffer = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tostring()
        texture = texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt = 'bgr')
        texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.image.texture = texture

    def take_picture(self, *args):
        image_name = "picture_at_2_02.png"
        cv2.imwrite(image_name, self.image_frame)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Kivy\main.py", line 2, in <module> from kivy.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout ImportError: cannot import name 'MDBoxLayout' from 'kivy.uix.boxlayout'`

I executed this code in the VSCode terminal window, but again an error occurred.

```
python3 -m pip install --force-reinstall git+https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD.git
```

```
python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program name All. Verify that the name is correct, verify that the path is correct if it is included, and then try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Those widgets are in `kivymd`. Change the import statements from `kivy.uix` to `kivymd.uix`.